# SDL with OpenGL start

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sfml

If I want to make a better performanced game, should I use SDL with OpenGL? Or I have to make pure OpenGL code without SDL.

Why OpenGL with SDL is better than pure SDL or pure OpenGL?

Or the best choice is to make the window management, and input handling with SDL, and the drawing with OpenGL?

I found very nice tutorials about OpenGL (http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/)

Can I use this tutorials combined with SDL?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, that if I want to make a better performanced game, should I use SDL with OpenGL?

Doesn't matter, actually.

> Or I have to make pure OpenGL code without SDL.

You have to create a window for your OpenGL somehow. If you do it yourself or using a framework makes no difference to OpenGL. The odds are that a newbie's window management will be not as elegant a properly written framework.

My advice: Usr a framework. Which one doesn't matter when it comes to performance.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://lazyfoo.net/) site has the answers you are looking for. Coincidentally, it also has SDL and OpenGL tutorials. Hope this helps!

Comment: In short, OpenGL is only a graphics API.  SDL give you the rest (events, windows, audio, file I/O, etc.)  Also review [this](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/Introduction) to see what SDL is providing.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So if I'm right I can use OpenGL like in the opengl-tutorial.org with SDL and I will get a more powerful/faster code than pure SDL?

Comment: @DurvaMan You will get a more powerful/faster graphics than with pure SDL. Pure SDL is pretty limited when it comes to graphics, and OpenGL is pure graphics. They complement each other quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Please read :

http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-opengl-tutorial-basics 
http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/guidevideoopengl.html

for development I recommended 'CodeLite' for any platform, or Visual Studio for windows